# Change Survey List Summary View

Tags: 2013, list, web-part, survey

How can i change the width of the results horizontal graph? Basically the view of the survey list is the summary.aspx of the Survey List.  End  goal is to show the survey in a small box in the lower right section as a webpart in the main page, so current dilemma is that the graphs are too long...

Here's the example -

[image]

I tried changing the css ms.surveyhbarb but im not sure which element is controlling the width.

This is Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes to control that

- A class called `ms-surveyHBar` for the blue section.
- A class called `ms-surveyHBarB` for the grayed section.

The two classes have only a `height property`, so you just need to add a new `width property` like this

```
<style>
    .ms-surveyHBarB
    {
    width: 50pt !important;
    }
</style>
```

**But I think this is will not match your requirement to show the survey in a small box in the lower right section as a web part in the main page! where the web part width will not change! as shown below**

[image]

**So in your case,**  you will need to create a custom web part to get survey graphical result and show it in a chart with your custom bars and width then add it in your page.

To can achieve that, check the code at,  [Getting survey graphical result](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79346/getting-survey-graphical-result)