# How to get a response from the survey list in SharePoint using JSOM or C#?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, jsom, survey, survey-list

I have a survey list name called "UserSurvey". I need to fetch the response from UserSuevey list using JSOM or C#.I referred the [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79346/getting-survey-graphical-result)

But i need more reference for that .please suggest me an idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample code for your reference.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //make changes based on your site url
        string siteurl = "http://sp:12001/";
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteurl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList Survey = web.Lists.TryGetList("Survey2");
                foreach(SPListItem item in Survey.Items){
                    //Question1 is your survey question, update/add based on your survey list questions.
                    Console.WriteLine(item["Question1"]);
                }

            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```